# Android - Parent activity should determine what child activity had called it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have 2 activities in my project, lets say Activity A, and Activity B. Both A and B **extend** the same superclass: BaseActivity.
We know that in this case, lets say if the Activity A is opened, then the superclass method onCreate() is called, and then the Activity A's onCreate() follows.

Being in the onCreate() method of the parent BaseActivity class, how can I determine which child activity has been started?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach.  Basically don't do inheritance.  Use composition instead.  Remember most operations that you think you need to extend for really just need a reference to the context.  Activities extend from context.  So really you can provide most base functionality in any class that has reference to an active context. No need to do inheritance at all.

So if you want to share some functionality between ActivityA and ActivityB just put it in HelperC

HelperC.someOperation(Context c, otherParams)

HelperC can do anything that some base activity could do.  Ultimately the base activity will never exist any way. It will always be an instantiated version A or B

Comment: Also please research composition vs. inheritance on Google to learn about the advantages of composition.  Its really has-a vs. is-a releationship.  For example is-a-doctor vs. is-a-person that has-a-doctor-role.  has-a is more flexible and dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do it this way.
As far as I remember the idea of extending, superclass method should contain only universal code. Puttin the differenting code in child classes would be much easier to do and as I believe more proper.

You can initilize some values in parent onCreate(), and then re-set it in childs'.